# VBA から (Strawberry Perlに入っている) GCC で作る関数 (DLL) を呼び出したい

Tags: vba, gcc, dll

VBA から　(Strawberry Perlに入っている) GCC で作る関数 (DLL) を呼び出したいのですが、何から調べれば良いですか？
ご指導よろしくお願いします。

Comment: VBAから呼び出されるDLLの関数は、C++かC#でプログラムを書く場合が多いです。なので、C++とC#でプログラムを書く方法を調べる事から始めるのが良いと思います。
ちなみに、DLLは"Dynamic Link Library"の略語で、ライブラリの一種です。その中に関数のプログラムが入っています。

Comment: 今の質問文だと「"Strawberry Perl付属の"gccだから使い方がわからない (別のコンパイラなら経験あり？)」「DLLの作成方法がわからない」「既存のDLLだとしてもVBAから呼び出す方法がわからない」など何パターンも考えられます。 / どの部分は理解していて、どこが分からないかをもう少し具体的に説明しておくと、回答が付きやすくなると思います。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Strawberry Perlに同梱されているgccはMinGW-w64のようなので、その辺のキーワードで検索した記事が参考になるでしょう。

[mingw-w64 GCC for Windows 64 & 32 bits](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php)

> Some Projects using Mingw-w64
>
> - [Strawberry Perl (bundles C toolchains)](http://strawberryperl.com/)

単に最小限のソースからDLLを作って呼べるように試したプロジェクト例
[rdinse/MSAccessSQL_DLL.md](https://gist.github.com/rdinse/0696f2cd3509a01237e5c3385dc54869)

少し古いかもな記事
[VB6, VBA の文字列 String を返す DLLを作成する](https://happynow.hateblo.jp/entry/20130825/1377404951)

32bit版での記事
[DLL compiled from C source code. Not able to use in excel VBA. File not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30265036/9014308)

実は解決していない記事
[Using MinGW gcc to create DLLs for VBA 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59110111/9014308)
[Unable to run C coded DLL in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61309881/9014308)

こちらはVBAではなくVisual Basic向けですが。
[Visual Basic DLL | MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_DLL)
[Compile a DLL in C/C++, then call it from another program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/847396/9014308)

上記でExcelから呼べた記事
[Excel won't load function from C++ DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11403981/9014308)

参考:VisualStudio系での記事
[DLLを作成してみる（その1）](http://dorapanda.asablo.jp/blog/2013/02/24/6729220)
[1章：DLLの作成方法とVBAから呼び出し方法](http://skomo.o.oo7.jp/f46/hp46_1.htm)
[ExcelのVBAで使えるDLLを、C++（Visual Studio 2017）で作る。・・・その１](https://z1000s.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/04/15/213852)

---

他には上記記事にも一部書かれていますが、VBA側の知識も必要でしょう。

DLLの関数をどう定義してどう呼び出すか、パラメータや戻り値は、といったことが説明されています。
[Excel で DLL にアクセスする](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/client-developer/excel/how-to-access-dlls-in-excel)

上記を含む開発キット(VisualStudio用?)の先頭ページ
[Excel ソフトウェア開発キットへようこそ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/client-developer/excel/welcome-to-the-excel-software-development-kit)

DLL経由でなくてもAPIを呼べたりしますが、方法とか(64bit時の)注意事項とか。
[VBAでWinAPI32を使うためのリンク集](https://qiita.com/Q11Q/items/16862ef1797e25cbadfd)

Comment: サンプルのコードを使ってコンパイルしました。コンパイルは成功しましたが、EXCELから呼び出しても認識しません。どうやらーW＊のオプションをサポートしていない様子です。素直にVisualStudioを使うのがいいみたいです。

Comment: まあ細かいことを悩んで時間がかかるよりも、今は個人使用程度ならVisualStudioが無料で使えますからね。